# For loop with unsigned int

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, unsigned

I have a logical problem in my code, maybe it is caused by overflowing but I can't solve this on my own, so I would be thankful if anyone can help me.

In the following piece of code, I have implemented the function taylor_log(), which can count "n" iterations of taylor polynomial. In the void function I am looking for number of iterations (*limit) which is enough to count a logarithm with desired accuracy compared to log function from .

The thing is that sometimes UINT_MAX is not enough iterations to get the desired accuracy and at this point I want to let the user know that the number of needed iterations is higher than UINT_MAX. But my code don't work, for example for x = 1e+280, eps = 623. It just counts, counts and never give result.

[TaylorPolynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7g0O.jpg)

```
double taylor_log(double x, unsigned int n){

    double f_sum = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f_sum *= (x - 1) / x;
        sum += f_sum / i;
    }

    return sum;
}


void guessIt(double x, double eps, unsigned int *limit){

    *limit = 10;
    double real_log = log(x);
    double t_log = taylor_log(x, *limit);
    while(myabs(real_log - t_log) > eps)
    {
        if (*limit == UINT_MAX)
        {
            *limit = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (*limit >= UINT_MAX/2)
        {
            *limit = UINT_MAX;
            t_log = taylor_log(x, *limit);
        }
        else
        {
            *limit = (*limit) *2;
            t_log = taylor_log(x, *limit);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ok guys, thanks for your reactions so far. I have changed my code to this:

```
if (*limit == UINT_MAX-1)
            {
                *limit = 0;
                break;
            }
if (*limit >= UINT_MAX/2)
            {
                *limit = UINT_MAX-1;
                t_log = taylor_log(x, *limit);
            }
```

but it still doesn't work correctly, I have set printf to the beggining of taylor_log() function to see the value of "n" and its (..., 671088640, 1342177280, 2684354560, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2013265920, ...). Don't understand it..

Comment: Is this in `C` or `C++`? (Looks like `C`).  As to your question - why not do some bounds checking before entering the loop?  You can put a hard bound on the acceptable input and ensure that this problem doesn't occur.  If you want to support arbitrarily large inputs, consider using `libgmp` or some other mathematical library that supports such calculations.

Comment: pick a language. `C` or `C++`, there is no such thing as `C/C++`

Comment: "I have implemented the function taylor_log()" --> This was done incorrectly so adding more terms will not solve the issue.

Comment: I have included image with a formula I have implemented, I think it's correct.

Comment: I agree you likely have coded per the image of the of the `log()` function.  The code below I suggested uses a different series.  I will need to look to see if your series is valid or just different.

Comment: mea culpa. I agree your code and reference formula are valid when used in the 0.5 < x < 2.0 range –

Answer (score 1):

This code below assigns the limit to UINT_MAX

```
if (*limit >= UINT_MAX/2)
{
    *limit = UINT_MAX;
    t_log = taylor_log(x, *limit);
}
```

And your for loop is defined like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

`i` will ALWAYS be less than or equal to `UINT_MAX` because there is never going to be a value of `i` that is greater than `UINT_MAX`. Because that's the largest value `i` could ever be. So there is certainly overflow and your loop exit condition is never met. `i` rolls over to zero and the process repeats indefinitely.

You should change your loop condition to `i < n` or change your limit to `UINT_MAX - 1`.

Comment: I think, in addition to that, your `myabs(real_log - t_log) > eps` condition is not being met, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: My mistake.  OP's formula does work in a limited range (0.5 < x < 2)

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

OP coded correctly but must insure a limited range (`0.5 < x < 2.0` ?)

Below is a code version that self determines when to stop.  Iteration count goes high near `x near 0.5 and 2.0`.  The iteration count needed goes into the millions.  Such the  alternative coded far below.

```
double taylor_logA(double x) {
  double f_sum = 1.0;
  double sum = 0.0;

  for (unsigned int i = 1; ; i++) {
    f_sum *= (x - 1) / x;
    double sum_before = sum;
    sum += f_sum / i;
    if (sum_before == sum) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      break;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

<strike>Wrong</strike>*alternative*  implementation of the series:  [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series)

Sample alternative - it converges faster.

```
double taylor_log2(double x, unsigned int n) {
  double f_sum = 1.0;
  double sum = 0.0;

  for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    f_sum *= (x - 1) / 1;  // / 1 (or remove)
    if (i & 1) sum += f_sum / i;
    else sum -= f_sum / i;  // subtract even terms
  }
  return sum;
}
```

A reasonable number of terms will converge as needed.

Alternatively, continue until terms are too small (maybe 50 or so)

```
double taylor_log3(double x) {
  double f_sum = 1.0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (unsigned int i = 1; ; i++) {
    double sum_before = sum;
    f_sum *= x - 1;
    if (i & 1) sum += f_sum / i;
    else sum -= f_sum / i;
    if (sum_before == sum) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Other improvements possible.  example [see More efficient series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series)

Answer (score 0):

First, using `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` will make your code more c++-ish than c-ish. Second, you can use the integral type `unsigned long long` and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` for the limit, which is pretty mush the limit for an integral type. If you want a higher limit, you may use `long double`. floating points also allows you to use infinity with `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` note that infinity work with `double`, `float` and `long double`.

If neither of these types provide you the precision you need, look at `boost::multiprecision`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Taylor series for the logarithm function only converges for values of 0 < x < 2, so it's quite possible that the `eps` precision is never hit.

Secondly, are you sure that it loops forever, instead of hitting the `*limit >= UINT_MAX/2` after a *very* long time?

Answer (score 0):

OP is using the series well outside its usable range of `0.5 x < 2.0` with calls like `taylor_log(1e280, n)`

Even within the range, `x` values near the limits of `0.5 and 2.0` converge very slowly needing millions+ of iterations.  A precise `log()` will not result.  Best to use the 2x range about 1.0.

Create a wrapper function to call the original function in its sweet range of `sqrt(2)/2 < x < sqrt(2)`.   Converges, worst case, with about 40 iterations.

```
#define SQRT_0_5  0.70710678118654752440084436210485
#define LN2       0.69314718055994530941723212145818

// Valid over the range (0...DBL_MAX]
double taylor_logB(double x, unsigned int n) {
  int expo;
  double signif = frexp(x, &expo);
  if (signif < SQRT_0_5) {
    signif *= 2;
    expo--;
  }
  double y = taylor_log(signif,n);
  y += expo*LN2;
  return y;
}
```